# Path to location of npm run call

Tags: node.js

I have a node script sitting at `project/bin/index.js`, and I added its execution command to `package.json`:

```
scripts: {
  "exec": "cd ./bin && npm -i --silent && node index.js"
}
```

I'm now able to run my node script from any location inside my project. The thing is that I want to do something depending on where I run this script, so I want to be able to get there the path telling from where I'm running my `npm run exec`. Is it possible? How can I do this?

`__filename`, `__dirname`, and `process.cwd()` return script path - `project/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can do this directly through npm scripts. My guess is that npm `cd`s to the project directory before running the command (as also evidenced by the fact that you can do `cd ./bin` or `node bin/index.js`). Yarn won't even let you run a command unless you are in the same directory as `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "exec": "npm i --silent && node bin/index.js $PWD"
}
```

index.js

```
console.log({
  __filename,
  __dirname,
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  execPath: process.execPath,
  pwd: process.env.PWD,
  argv: process.argv
});
```

shell env

```
Jasons-MBP-2:some-dir jason$ env
PWD=/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run/some-dir
```

run

```
Jasons-MBP-2:some-dir jason$ npm run exec

> npm-run@1.0.0 exec /Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run
> npm i --silent && node bin/index.js $PWD
```

result

```
{ __filename: '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run/bin/index.js',
  __dirname: '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run/bin',
  cwd: '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run',
  execPath: '/Users/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/node',
  pwd: '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run',
  argv:
  [ '/Users/jason/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/node',
    '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run/bin/index.js',
    '/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run' ] }
```

Comment: Well, `$PWD` in `package.json` is undefined. Maybe the syntax is wrong?

Comment: $PWD comes through as the 3rd value in argv, `/Users/jason/Development/so/npm-run` (on my macOS at least..)